# R - merge two dataframes - Error in sort.list(bx[m$xi]) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to merge to dataframe by key_date that set in each of them:

```
> merge <- merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = "key_date", all.x = TRUE)
```

Error:

```
Error in sort.list(bx[m$xi]) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

The structure of df1:

```
'data.frame':   192 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ date    : POSIXct, format: "2017-02-03 00:00:00" ...
 $ NO2     : num  7.4 6.7 7 6.1 5.8 8.8 9 8.5 8.1 7.6 ...
 $ key_date: POSIXlt, format: "2017-02-03" ...
 $ site    : chr  "anon1" "anon1" "anon1" "anon1" ...
 $ code    : chr  "anon1" "anon1" "anon1" "anon1" ...
```

The structure of df2:

```
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ airport : chr  "LCY" "LCY"
 $ key_date: chr  "2017-02-04" "2017-02-03"
 $ ws      : num  4 13
 $ wd      : num  161 185
 $ tempi   : num  7 8
 $ humidity: num  85 78

> dput(df2)
structure(list(airport = c("LCY", "LCY"), key_date = c("2017-02-04", 
"2017-02-03"), ws = c(4, 13), wd = c(161, 185), tempi = c(7, 
8), humidity = c(85, 78)), .Names = c("airport", "key_date", 
"ws", "wd", "tempi", "humidity"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

What has gone wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: you've specified `x = df1`, but your example data is called `df` (without the 1)

Comment: @SymbolixAU my mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`df2$key_data` is of class different to that of `df1`

```
#df2$key_date <- as.Date(df2$key_date, "%Y-%M-%d")
df2$key_date <- as.POSIXct(df2$key_date)
mdf <- merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = "key_date", all.x = TRUE)
```

EDIT:

There is a difference in dates in "AEST" and "GMT" with the times in two df's.

```
df2$key_date <- as.POSIXct(df2$key_date)

df2$key_date
# [1] "2017-02-04 AEST" "2017-02-03 AEST"

df1$key_date
#[1] "2017-02-03 GMT" "2017-02-03 GMT" "2017-02-03 GMT" "2017-02-03 GMT"
#[5] "2017-02-03 GMT" "2017-02-03 GMT"

df2$key_date <- as.character(df2$key_date)
df1$key_date <- as.character(df1$key_date)
merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = "key_date", all.x = TRUE)

# key_date                date NO2 PM10_1 PM10_2 PM10_3  site  code
# 1 2017-02-03 2017-02-03 10:00:00 7.4   18.3     NA     NA anon1 anon1
# 2 2017-02-03 2017-02-03 10:15:00 6.7     NA   27.5     NA anon1 anon1
# 3 2017-02-03 2017-02-03 10:30:00 7.0     NA   27.9     NA anon1 anon1
# 4 2017-02-03 2017-02-03 10:45:00 6.1     NA   28.9     NA anon1 anon1
# 5 2017-02-03 2017-02-03 11:00:00 5.8   21.1   28.2     NA anon1 anon1
# 6 2017-02-03 2017-02-03 11:15:00 8.8     NA   28.1     NA anon1 anon1
# airport ws  wd tempi humidity
# 1     LCY 13 185     8       78
# 2     LCY 13 185     8       78
# 3     LCY 13 185     8       78
# 4     LCY 13 185     8       78
# 5     LCY 13 185     8       78
# 6     LCY 13 185     8       78
```

Comment: thanks. I found the format error in key_date in my df1. it should have been `chr`.

Comment: yeah, it wouldn't work even if you _just_ change it to 'as.POSIXct' because the times are measured in different time zones.

Comment: Ideally, I'd covert them to data's in the same time zone than characters.

Comment: @Headpoint - I suspect using the numeric representation of the datetime would be more efficient that converting to characters.

Comment: @SymbolixAU, I think it might come handy if you want to see the distance between dates etc, later on. I wasn't just taking about the merging. I could still be wrong though.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is because the format of your key dates are not the same in the two data frames, One is a character and the other one is a POSIXct
convert them to the same format and try again.

Comment: thanks. I found the format error in key_date in my df1. it should have been `chr`.